# OpenModelica Custom block jittery behavior

Tags: openmodelica

In my OpenModelica model, I added a custom block to simulate the behavior of a push-pull bar. This behavior can be seen as three different spring stiffnesses. Which spring stiffness needs to be used is based on the position of the push-pull bar. I modelled this with an if-statement as can be seen below:

```
block VariableSpringStiffness
  extends Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.PartialCompliant;
  import Modelica.Units.SI;

  // Variable instead of parameter
  SI.TranslationalSpringConstant c "Spring constant";
  parameter SI.Distance s_rel0=0 "Unstretched spring length";
  Real s1 = 1/1000 "Slack M90 bolt [m]";
  Real s2 = 12/1000 "Displacement Push-Pull bar [m]";
  Real f0 = 281e3;

equation
  // Initialize variable c based on conditions
  if abs(s_rel) < s1 then
    c = f0/s1 "Preload over slack [N/m]";
  elseif abs(s_rel) < s2 then
    c = 35e3/s2 "Spring stiffness";
  else
    c = 2e11 "Material stiffness";
  end if;

  // Rest of the equations
  f = 2*c * (s_rel - s_rel0);  // 2 springs
end VariableSpringStiffness;
```

This code works, but the behavior is very jittery, as the spring stiffness sometimes changes per time step. Is there a way to smooth this behavior out, preferably without interpolation and using the spring stiffness provided.